# How to install and run postgress using docker-compose.yml version "1"

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, postgresql-9.4, docker-machine

**1: docker-compose.yml**

```
postgres96:
  image: postgres:9.6
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  volumes:
    - ./Postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  env:    
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin@123
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
```

**2)** **$ docker-compose up &**

```
postgres96_1      | LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
postgres96_1      | LOG:  invalid record length at 0/1570D50: wanted 24, got 0
postgres96_1      | LOG:  redo is not required
postgres96_1      | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
postgres96_1      | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres96_1      | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

But while testing from **pg-admin-iv** on windows it show that *'user postgress has no password'*,

**So is that flow from YML file is right, i want simply up the postgress and put data out side docker-container, so How to achieve this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use **named volumes** for that instead of hosted mapped volumes:

```
postgres96:
  image: postgres:9.6
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  volumes:
    - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  environment:    
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin@123
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
```

Probably you have a permission issue in your folder.

You data is saved in a volume outside the container. Then check with:

```
docker volume ls
```

Also use docker-compose as:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Instead of **&**

And

```
docker-compose logs -f
```

For further information this is the last part of my log:

```
postgres96_1  | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
postgres96_1  |
postgres96_1  | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2016-11-14 21:05:51 UTC
postgres96_1  | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
postgres96_1  | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres96_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
postgres96_1  | LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

Regards

Comment: Hi @Carlos, thanks for reply, I done changes as you suggested, but the default 'postgres' user doesn't have permission to create a new database, so what other things need to add or follow in docker-compose.yml, suppose after postgress container is up then we have to do DB operation like create new DB, etc...

Comment: HI, I removed postgres_user and postgres_password from yml file and now I am able to create new DB and tables, but all the data is stored in 'pg_stat_tmp' directory which is in progress data folder, so how to cross check that data is stored outside of docker container and new data is added in db, etc.....?

Comment: Hello, destroy the container `docker-compose down -v` it will destroy it and also the volumes but the named volumes. Then create a new container using `docker-compose up -d` and you should see your tables there